# Is asio::serial_port able to check physical disconnection?

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I'm working with boost::asio library for serial communications, and got some problems using it. Below is my code with the problem.

```
std::unique_ptr<asio::serial_port> port_;
asio::io_service io_;

// Connect serial port 'COM8'
port_ = std::make_unique<asio::serial_port>(asio::serial_port(io_, "COM8"));
std::cout << port_->is_open() << std::endl; // True

Sleep(5000);
/// **Now I unplug the device connected to the COM8 port of my PC.**

std::cout << port_->is_open() << std::endl;
/// Still printed true.
/// I think the reason @asio::serial_port::is_open() returns true 
/// is because I didn't called @asio::serial_port::close() before. 
/// Then how can I check the physical disconnection?
```

After I unplugged the device, how can I know whether the device is still available in programmatically?

Comment: `is_open()` if the class instance is "open".  Basically, if it's allowed to to call operations on the instance. Perhaps there is some way to use native handle to detect loss of communication but it won't be portable. Usually after creating a socket one assigns reading/writing routines, and when that routine fails do we get indication that something is off with the socket.

Comment: Serial port communication does not have a way of detecting connection/disconnection, because there is no regular heartbeat or keep-alive messages at the protocol level. You have to implement this by yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect it when attempting a read/write operation:

E.g. from the [exception overload of `write_some`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_serial_port/write_some/overload1.html):

> **boost::system::system_error**
>
> Thrown on failure. An error code of `boost::asio::error::eof` indicates
> that the connection was closed by the peer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @sehe, this is my solution. (method which has `port_` as its private memeber variable)

```
inline bool _IsConnected() {
  bool connected = (port_ != nullptr && port_->is_open());
  if (connected) {
    try {
      // Sned any string that doesn't define
      // in your communication protocol.
      std::string s = "0"; 
      port_->write_some(asio::buffer("0"));
    }
    catch (const std::exception& err) {
      connected = false;
    }
  }
  return connected;
}
```